# how to know that pear installed on windows 8

Tags: php, pear

how to know that pear installed on windows 8.

i downloaded go-pear.phar and install it but how to check?

http://pear.php.net/
PEAR is a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php
I found that link is helpful
You have to run reg.env first